# MVC2 AJAX - determining UpdateTargetId based on the returned data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

**The scenario:**

I'm creating a login form for an MVC2 application.

**How i'm doing it**:

The form submits to an MVC2 action which validates the username/password. If it fails validation the action returns the form (a partial view) for the user to try again. If it passes validation the action returns the page the user was visiting before they logged in (a view).

**What i want to happen:**

1 - when the form is submitted and the user validates successfully, The returned result should replace the current page (like what happens if you don't set an UpdateTargetId).

2 - When the form is submitted and the user fails validation, the returned result should replace the form (like what happens if you set the UpdateTargetID to the form's containing element).

**The problem:**

I can make both of those things work, but not at the same time. I can either have it always replace the current page, or always just replace the contents of the UpdateTargetId element. But I need it to be able to do either depending on whether the user successfully validated or not.

**What I need**

The ideal solution would be to be able to examine the result of the ajax request and determine whether to use the UpdateTargetId (replacing just the form) or not (replacing the whole page). I expect it would involve some work with jquery (assuming it's possible) but i'm not really that great with jquery yet to figure out how to do it myself. If it can't be done this way I'm also open to other methods/solutions for making it work in a similar fashion.

Thanks in advance ..

As requested. Code for the action. But as i said. It's the standard LogOn action that ships default with every mvc application. The only difference is it returns a partial view when validation fails.

```
[HttpPost]
    [MedLife.Code.Compression.CompressFilter]
    public ActionResult SignIn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return PartialView("Overlays/LoginControl", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you return a Json result with the string "INVALID" if the login/password is invalid. Then you use the UpdateTargetId.

If the Json result != "INVALID" then you would replace the container with new partial page.

That's how I do it and it works great. :-)

Comment: That's good, but the issue is more **how** do i make it use the UpdateTargetId or not. I either set the UpdateTargetId in the ajax i don't. How do i make it determine whether to use it programmatically depending on whether this string is present like you suggest.

Comment: Got it to work acceptably doing it this way (or at least very similarly to this way).

Answer (score 1):

In your server side code, check to see if the validation works, if not, return a RedirectToAction to whatever full view you need.

The issue you have is all application logic, as opposed to display logic, so it should be done in the Controller rather than the view to keep your concerns separate.

You have to do a RedirectToAction (ie, not just return View("myViewWhenInvalid");) because otherwise the view will be rendered in the UpdateTargetID, which won't look good.

EDIT:

Ie:

```
public ActionResult myLoginAction(string name, string pwd)
{
// do the login stuff
if (loggedIn) 
{
return RedirectToAction(...);
}
else
{
return MyJsonAction();
}
}

public MyJsonAction()
{
return some Json...;
}
```

PS:  I have a cold, so disinclined to check my idea.

Comment: All application logic already works. The controller already returns a RedirectToAction if login is successful. The problem is how to display the result of the ajax request. If the login was successful then the returned result is a full page and needs to replace the current full page. If the login was unsuccessul then the returned result is a partial view and needs to replace a target div. I can make it do either one or the other of those 2 things. But i can't make it select which one to do depending on which result was returned. That is my problem.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is your expectation of how things should work.  Ie, you are fighting the framework.  New projects are created with a ready to go AccountController that deals with all your membership stuff.  Have you tried using that?

Comment: actually the ready to go AccountController is what i'm using. The only thing I've changed about the standard login is a new form that uses AJAX. When the LogOn action succedes and returns a RedirectToAction (which displays a full page) that full page gets displayed inside of the UpdateTargetID. If you have it display the result as a full page then you have the opposite problem: if the login fails and it returns the login form partial view (+ model errors), then the partial view replaces the full page (also undesirable)

Comment: BECAUSE you are NOT redirecting to a different Action!!.  RedirectToAction sends a redirect response (302, I think) to the browser, telling it which Action to redirect to.  That way, you wipe out your login page:  the redirect response writes NOTHING to the browser, it just tells it to forget what it wanted to do and go get another page, regardless of how the initial request started and what it expects.

Comment: I think what you must be doing is, instead of return RedirectToAction, you are doing return View(...).  Edit your question and shows us some code.

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");  Looks like RedirectToAction to me :p. As i said, i'm using the standard AccountController, which already uses return RedirectToAction.

Comment: I added the code for the action, but nothings changed other than to return a partial view when logon fails